# logout user from button on BottomNavigationBar using flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add a button for the user to logout on the `BottomNavigationBar` widget but I am not sure how to do it since it doesn't have an `onPressed` method. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'logout'),
  ],
  onTap: (index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      // implement your signout logic here
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give it a try.

Comment: @LostTexan Let me know if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Inkwell" widget.

```
Inkwell(onTap:(){ 
//your sign out codes
},
child: //your sign out child 
),
```